# django-tenant-schema and domain redirection

Tags: python, django, redirect, multi-tenant

I'm currently using django-tenant-schemas but I have one doubt, given that my scenario requires that tenants are not presented with an URL in the form:

```
tenant1.domain.com
tenant2.domain.com
```

and so on

But I need to have an URL that does not show the domain part for each tenant...is that possible?

Let's say I do have a domain for each tenant, which is actually true, for instance:

```
tenant1.com
```

And that I do have access to the Zone file for that domain, so I can create a subdomain for it:

```
app.tenant1.com
```

Can I somehow redirect any request from `app.tenant1.com` to my django schema that has the form `tenant1.domain.com`?

Comment: If anyone stumbles here, I'm gonna do this with domain redirection using Amazon route 53.